# Тесты cucumber spring junit . Поднимать контекст только для определенных сценариев

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, cucumber

Всем привет. Хочу написать сценарии тестов на cucumber. При этом использовать в шагах реализации cucumber поля которые внедряются спрингом. Это получилось сделать, но теперь мне нужно чтобы контекст спринга инициализировался только с определенными тестами. Как я могу это сделать? Например с помощью аннотации в сценариях тестов

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Appconfiguration.class})
public class BasePageStepDefs {
```

Comment: Вы же специально сделали, чтоб контекст поднимался. Это можно сделать разными способами. Как вы сделали из вопроса не ясно. Чтоб можно было вам посоветовать что-то, покажите пример теста в котором контекст поднимается, а нужно сделать чтоб не поднимался.

Comment: Я просто аннотировал @ContextConfiguration(classes=Appconfiguration.class) классы stepDef где реализуются шаги кукумбера.

Comment: таким образом получилось сделать чтобы context поднимался для всех сценариев , но мне нужно что бы только для тех которые я хочу